# Looking at YouTube and google I created Code for a simple Jpanel with Button However What the videos don't tell me is what Design patterns am i using

Tags: java, design-patterns

I created an application which allows instantiating shapes which can be circle rectangle or anything and used sorting technique (Bubble Sort) to sort the six shapes based on interfaces.

The problem is I am not familiar with Design patterns and what patterns are being used- I am new so i followed youtube videos and played around with it and it worked.

I have 1 main class where I have
MAIN :

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JButton btnLoadShapes, btnSortShapes;
    
    btnLoadShapes = new JButton("Load Shapes");
    btnLoadShapes.setBounds(150, 10, 150, 30);
    
    btnSortShapes = new JButton("Sort Shapes");
    btnSortShapes.setBounds(310, 10, 150, 30);
    
    
    JPanel panelShapes = new JPanel() {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            
            Shape shape = new Shape();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            Square s = shape.getS();
        
            g2d.fillRect(s.getX(),s.getY(),s.getWidth(), s.getHeight());
        
            
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            Circle c = shape.getC();
            g2d.fillOval(c.getX(),c.getY(), c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
            
            g2d.setColor(new Color(131, 21, 1));
            Rectangle r = shape.getR();
            g2d.fillRect(r.getX(), r.getY(), r.getWidth(), r.getHeight());
            
            g2d.setColor(Color.PINK);
            Circle C1 = shape.getC1();
            g2d.fillOval(C1.getX(),C1.getY(), C1.getWidth(), C1.getHeight());
            
            g2d.setColor(Color.green);
            Square S1 = shape.getS1();
            g2d.fillRect(S1.getX(),S1.getY(),S1.getWidth(), S1.getHeight());
            
            g2d.setColor(Color.magenta);
            Rectangle r2 = shape.getR2();
            g2d.fillRect(r2.getX(),r2.getY(),r2.getWidth(), r2.getHeight());
            
            
            
            
            
        } 

    };
    
    panelShapes.setBounds(10, 50, 560, 500);
    panelShapes.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    panelShapes.setVisible(false);
    
    btnLoadShapes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            panelShapes.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

and i have created 3 different classes Circle Rectangle and Square - from which i call for rectangle = shape.getC();
For example
public class Circle {
private int x, y, width, height;

```
public Circle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}
```

}

Now the lastly I created 2 more classes called Shape and Sorting
where in shape i intiated public shape s = new Square with dimensions and set getters and setters and lastly i used sorting technique.

Can someone help me understand what are the design patterns that are being used here?
( I assume that Factory method is being used = since i defined main (* interface) and created subclasses ( Shapes rectangle circle) to instantiate.

Sorry if i sound out the place- I am just trying to understand and learn it.

Comment: The code is out of context, but, based on `public class Circle {`, I wouldn't say you're using an actual "factory" pattern, as a "factory" would return a base representation, the implementation details been unimportant.  Like a `Car`, but the factory could produce a `Ford` or `Tesla`, but they are still a instance of `Car`

Comment: I have updated the Codes let me know if that helps

Comment: It seems very strange to write some code and assume it's a pattern. Firstly, you don't need to use any pattern to write code. Secondly, if you want to learn about patterns, then why not study patterns? There are plenty of books, videos, blogs, etc. where you don't need to guess. Thirdly, patterns are not a good way to learn programming, IMO. They are not a beginner/introductory topic. Knowing how to code _without_ patterns is more valuable than knowing patterns. Patterns are secondary.

Answer (score 1):

A "factory" creates "something", the important thing in this context is, you don't care "how" it's created, only that it conforms to the specified type.

For example, you have a `ShapeFactory` which can create different shapes, you don't care "how" those shapes are defined or implemented, only that they conform to the notion of a "shape"

So, lets start with a basic concept...

```
public interface Shape {
    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d);
}
```

This just defines a basic concept and states that it can be painted.

Next, we need something to create those shapes...

```
public class ShapeFactory {
    
    enum ShapeType {
        CIRCLE, RECTANGE, SQUARE;
    }
    
    public static Shape create(ShapeType type, int x, int y, int width, int height, Color storkeColor, Color fillColor) {
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

Ok, as it stands, that's pretty boring, it's only ever going to return `null` right now, but this gives us a basic contract.

"Please factory, create me shape of the specified type, within the specified bounds, with the specified colors"

Now, as I said, the implementation is unimportant, to the caller, and we could have a dynamic factory which could delegate the creation to other factories which could create shapes differently based on a wide ranging set of needs ... but that's getting ahead of ourselves.

Let's go about creating some actual shapes...

```
public abstract class AbstractShape implements Shape {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    
    private Color storkeColor;
    private Color fillColor;

    public AbstractShape(Color storkeColor, Color fillColor) {
        this.storkeColor = storkeColor;
        this.fillColor = fillColor;
    }

    public AbstractShape(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color storkeColor, Color fillColor) {
        this(storkeColor, fillColor);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    protected void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    protected void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    protected void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    protected void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Color getStorkeColor() {
        return storkeColor;
    }

    public Color getFillColor() {
        return fillColor;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
        Color storkeColor = getStorkeColor();
        Color fillColor = getFillColor();
        
        if (fillColor != null) {
            g.setColor(fillColor);
            paintFilled(g);
        }
        
        if (storkeColor != null) {
            g.setColor(storkeColor);
            paintStroked(g);
        }
        g.dispose();
    }
    
    abstract protected void paintFilled(Graphics2D g2d);
    abstract protected void paintStroked(Graphics2D g2d);
    
}

public class CircleShape extends AbstractShape {

    public CircleShape(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color storkeColor, Color fillColor) {
        super(storkeColor, fillColor);
        int size = Math.min(width, height);
        x = x + ((width - size) / 2);
        y = y + ((height - size) / 2);
        
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
        setWidth(size);
        setHeight(size);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintFilled(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.fillOval(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintStroked(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.drawOval(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    
}
       
public class SquareShape extends AbstractShape {

    public SquareShape(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color storkeColor, Color fillColor) {
        super(storkeColor, fillColor);
        int size = Math.min(width, height);
        x = x + ((width - size) / 2);
        y = y + ((height - size) / 2);
        
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
        setWidth(size);
        setHeight(size);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintFilled(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintStroked(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.drawRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    
}
       
public class RectagleShape extends AbstractShape {

    public RectagleShape(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color storkeColor, Color fillColor) {
        super(x, y, width, height, storkeColor, fillColor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintFilled(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintStroked(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.drawRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    
}
```

I always like a `abstract` class to carry the "common" functionality and to help make life a little simpler.

The important thing here is to note that both `CircleShape` and `SquareShape`, by their nature are, well, square (they have equal width and height).  So, in this implementation, I define them to fit within the middle of the specified bounds - this is a "implementation" detail.

"But isn't that what I'm doing you?" you ask.  Well, no, not really.  When you call `shape.getS()`, for example, it's return a concrete class, which I assume has the same properties as the last object created by it, otherwise it will move all over the place.

Instead, what I'm doing is allowing you to define the properties you want the shape to have and then making it.

You want a cake?  Sure, pass me the ingredients and I'll make you  a cake, you still end up with a cake, but depending on the ingredients it's a different "type" of cake.

So, based on the above, we could do something like...

[image: All your shape belong to us]

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {
    
    private List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>(25);
    
    public TestPane() {
        shapes.add(ShapeFactory.create(ShapeFactory.ShapeType.CIRCLE, 10, 10, 200, 100, Color.RED, Color.BLUE));
        shapes.add(ShapeFactory.create(ShapeFactory.ShapeType.RECTANGE, 10, 120, 200, 100, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN));
        shapes.add(ShapeFactory.create(ShapeFactory.ShapeType.SQUARE, 10, 240, 200, 100, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(220, 350);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        for (Shape shape : shapes) {
            shape.paint(g2d);
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }
    
}
```

I could have made the `ShapeFactory` with dedicated `createCircle`, `createRectangle` and `createSquare` methods, I could have had them return `interfaces` of `Circle`, `Square` and `Rectangle` (and I would have based those of `Shape` because I'm like that) and it would still be a factory.

One of things to keep in mind is, a "factory" should be implementation independent.  I should be able to make use of "different" shape factories to get different effects, but at the end of the day, they'd still just be generating `Shape`s

Remember, a factory will take something and it will create something from it.